# How to achieve maximum concurrency on a Azure Worker role

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-worker-roles

Is it possible to find out how many concurrent threads we can start on a worker role considering the current environment we are running on. It seems that we can't really rely on the numbers of cores as the resources sharing is not directly tied to one physical core. 
Taking an example of a small instance how many concurrent background worker can I have running simultaneously ( CPU bound off course ! ).

Is there any way we can do that dynamically as well (if we choose to scale up to another type of instance)

Thanks

Comment: This is a Windows Server question really, as a Worker Role instance is a Windows Server 2012 VM with dedicated RAM and CPU based on which size you choose.

Comment: That's entirely up to you. The smaller the workload, the more threads you can run effectively in parallel. Usually I leverage the Task Parallel Library (TPL) and specify a maximum number of threads that it will not exceed; I let the TPL determine how many threads make sense based on the current server specifications. For the type of workloads I run, I usually set the MAX Threads to 4 times the number of cores available on the VM instance, which you can easily find programmatically.